# Magento - Form field validate against list

Tags: forms, validation

I am currently using Magento version 1.9. I would like to create a form with one field of data validation against a list of finite numbers (A list that I can upload in the back-end of Magento). The user will enter a unique number to match the number on the list I've uploaded previously. In order to continue with the form, there can be a validate button to validate the number on the form before submitting the entire form. Example form screenshot below. How can this be done?

[image: screenshot]

Thank you for your time, 
Elvis

Comment: Can you someone please help?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So I assume that this form will have a controller with an action my suggestion would be to add the validation into the php side when the form is submitted.

If there is an error when submitting the form then add the message to the session and redirect the user to the same page and show the error messages.

Have a look at how the core `Mage_Customer_AccountController` works when posting data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you can use magento form validation or can built your own.

See [this](http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/) and this [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/validate-your-input-magento-style/).

> *Magento uses Prototype library to manage form validation. This comes
>   in handy, because all you need to do when writing custom form is to
>   assign a valid class names to your input fields, and pass the form id
>   to VarienForm object.*

*Or else you should follow "David Manners" answer.*